# Fade between DIVS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make fading effect between multiple divs.
But it is not working, please can anyone help me "Im new in javascript"
This is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KBGp7/3/) from where I generate the code.
In this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KBGp7/3/) the code work very well but when i copy the code, it stop working.
Hope my question is clear ! THANKS
This is the code that I try to copy.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

txt1 = $("#contentarea-1").text();
txt2 = $("#contentarea-2").text();

$("#pg1").on('click', function () {
    $('#contentarea-2').hide();
    $('#contentarea-1').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $("#contentarea-1").hide(txt2);
        $('#contentarea-1').fadeIn(500);
    });
});

$("#pg2").on('click', function () {
    $('#contentarea-1').hide();
    $('#contentarea-2').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $("#contentarea-2").text(txt2);
        $('#contentarea-2').fadeIn(500);
    });
});

</script>

<style>
#content-wrapper{
    margin-left: 50px;
}
#contentarea-1{
    width: 450px;
}

#contentarea-2{
    width: 450px;
    display:none;
}

#clear{
    clear: both;
}

nav{
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
}
</style>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#1" id="pg1">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2" id="pg2">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="contentarea-1">
        <wbr><p>FIRST PAGE</p></wbr>
    </div>
    <div id="contentarea-2">
        <wbr><p> SECOND PAGE</p></wbr>
    </div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The fiddles are the same; but are you executing your function in $(document).ready function? Checked your console for errors?

Comment: "it stop working" Is it the message in your console?

Comment: Thanks all of  you. Edward you are right I forget to execute my function in $document. ready, so I added this code and it is working good !

Answer (score 2):

There's only a slight change required. You forgot to wrap your javascript in a jquery `domready` container:

http://jsfiddle.net/3tx8u/

```
<script>
$(function() {
    txt1 = $("#contentarea-1").text();
    txt2 = $("#contentarea-2").text();

    $("#pg1").on('click', function () {
        $('#contentarea-2').hide();
        $('#contentarea-1').fadeOut(500, function () {
            $("#contentarea-1").hide(txt2);
            $('#contentarea-1').fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
    $("#pg2").on('click', function () {
        $('#contentarea-1').hide();
        $('#contentarea-2').fadeOut(500, function () {
            $("#contentarea-2").text(txt2);
            $('#contentarea-2').fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks you Paul I execute my function in $document. ready... and it is working good !

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute your code inside the [`document ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

> Description: Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully
>   loaded.

It ensure that all your page objects are loaded into the DOM before try to access and use them.

In jsFiddle your code works because you choosed to run the script-code in "onload", in your real code without onload you have to use document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    txt1 = $("#contentarea-1").text();
    txt2 = $("#contentarea-2").text();
    $("#pg1").on('click', function () {
        $('#contentarea-2').hide();
        $('#contentarea-1').fadeOut(500, function () {
            $("#contentarea-1").hide(txt2);
            $('#contentarea-1').fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
    $("#pg2").on('click', function () {
        $('#contentarea-1').hide();
        $('#contentarea-2').fadeOut(500, function () {
            $("#contentarea-2").text(txt2);
            $('#contentarea-2').fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/KBGp7/4/